# Выполнение тригер по условию

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Вот описал как мог, оно конечно же не работает

```
IF
SELECT * FROM `temp` WHERE `session_id` != NEW.session_id 
THEN
INSERT INTO `temp` (`session_id`, `temp`) VALUES (NEW.session_id, 'data')
END IF
```

Как условие такого рода можно реализовать?

Comment: Какая исходная задача?

Comment: может вы хотели сделать `insert into temp(session_id, temp) select NEW.session_id, 'data' from DUAL where not exists(select 1 from temp where session_id=NEW.session_id)`

Comment: @Mike, совершенно верно, благодарю вас!

Comment: А может просто создать уникальный индекс на `session_id` да вставлять с использованием `insert ignore`? Тогда никакие проверки не нужны, СУБД сама не запишет дубликат. Это надёжнее...

Comment: @Mike может быть, ответ опубликуете?